# How to create a custom layout component in Form.io that has hardcoded values (no dialog for options)

Tags: javascript, formio

I'm using Form.io builder as the main form builder of my application.

One of my client's requests was to create a few draggable components from the side menu called "2 columns", "3 columns" and "4 columns".

Once you drag this components you'll get the existing "columns" component from the `formio` package with the 2/3/4 columns predefined (so no dialog is opened to start messing with the component settings.

Here is an example:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create components (one folder per each) based off formiojs\components\columns but there are tons of other edits to do on WebformBuilder.js, WebformBuilder.uit.js, etc

possible but not easy